# nvidia-smi monitor only while a specific process is running

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nvidia-smi

In bash, `nvidia-smi` command gives you information about the GPU.
We also have option to get this periodically such as `nvidia-smi -lms 50`

I want to get this info only as long as a particular process is running.

Pseudocode

```
nvidia-smi -lms 50 & > logfile.txt
(time ./process1) > timelog.txt
while process1 is running:
     keep nvidia-smi running
kill nvidia-smi
```

How can I do this in bash, *cleanly*, such that once my bash script exits no process that starts here is left behind for me to clean?
A direct `nvidia-smi` based solution would be preferred to a bash based one, but the latter is also perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run both in the background, then wait for the one your job depends on.

```
nvidia-smi -lms 50 > logfile.txt &
nvpid=$!
time ./process1 > timelog.txt &
prpid=$!
wait "$prpid"
kill "$nvpid"
```